# strcmp() and strcat() sequence

Tags: c, string, pointers

On my way to hone my C skills with a C Pointers literature, I came across this code. In this problem, I am supposed to justify the output. I am familiar with working of `strcat()` and `strcmp()`. I know that `strcmp()` returns 0 when the two strings passed, are same.

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <string.h>
int main()
{
    static char str1[]="Good";
    static char str2[20];
    static char str3[20] ="Day";

    int l;      

    l = strcmp(strcat(str3, strcpy(str2, str1)), strcat(str3, "good"));

    printf("%d\n", l);
    return 0;
}
```

The answer provided there is 0, which means that two calculated strings must be same. I tried to solve the statement in multiple steps.

First, tried `strcat(str3, strcpy(str2, str1))`.
'str2' gets changed to "Good", then `strcat()` changes `str3` to `DayGood'.
My gcc compiler agrees with me so far.

Coming to `strcat(str3, "good")`, since str3 has been changed to `DayGood` already, `strcat` changes `str3` to `DayGoodgood`.

Again, gcc agress with me.

```
int main()
{
    static char str1[]="Good";
    static char str2[20];
    static char str3[20] ="Day";

    int l;
    printf("%s\n", strcat(str3, strcpy(str2, str1)));
    printf("%s\n", strcat(str3, "good"));       

    //l = strcmp(strcat(str3, strcpy(str2, str1)), strcat(str3, "good"));

    //printf("%d\n", l);
    return 0;
}
```

It produces

```
DayGood

DayGoodgood
```

I again tried this variation.

```
int main()
{
    static char str1[]="Good";
    static char str2[20];
    static char str3[20] ="Day";

    int l;

    printf("%s\n", strcat(str3, "good"));
    printf("%s\n", strcat(str3, strcpy(str2, str1)));

    //l = strcmp(strcat(str3, strcpy(str2, str1)), strcat(str3, "good"));

    //printf("%d\n", l);
    return 0;
}
```

It produces.

```
Daygood
DaygoodGood
```

In my both test cases, I get two different strings for comparison. Why is then `strcmp()` is producing a 0 ?

Comment: All sorts of undefined and unspecified behavior all over the place, don't even try to reason about 'em...

Comment: I'm not sure there's anything undefined. The final content of `str3` may be dependent on unspecified evaluation order, but function calls in unknown order aren't as bad as `x=x++`-ish things, and I don't think any of the possible orders will overflow a buffer. The important fact is that `str3` equals itself in the end.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley The contents of `str3` are modified more than once between sequence points.

Comment: @H2CO3: Yes, That's what I think too. Answers are being flooded with str3 with being compared to str3. But content of str3 are too being modified.

Comment: @H2CO3 I believe the completion of the inner `strcat` provides a sequence point where its side effects are committed before the outer one is called.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley I think I'll have to double check this. Now I'm not sure.

Comment: At least we can be pretty sure that whoever wrote this code intended it as a trick question... either "spotting unordered function calls" or "noticing that a string equals itself". It surely doesn't teach how to use string functions sanely

Comment: Would be a cumbersome interview question:)

Comment: @H2CO3 Annex C is sequence points.

Comment: @sgun Only if you can provide [a spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strcat.html) that the interviewee can refer to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a quick way to get the answer without tracing all the calls: both arguments to the `strcat` are returned from `strcpy`s with the first arg `str3`, and since `strcpy` returns its first arg, that means the final call is `strcmp(str3, str3)` which of course will be 0 no matter what weird manipulations have been done on it.

In response to the updated question, try this and see if you get enlightened:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
    static char str1[]="Good";
    static char str2[20];
    static char str3[20] ="Day";
    char *first, *second;

    printf("str3 = %p => %s\n", (void *)str3, str3);

    first = strcat(str3, strcpy(str2, str1));
    printf("first strcat returned %p => %s\n", (void *)first, first);
    printf("and now str3 = %p => %s\n", (void *)str3, str3);

    second = strcat(str3, "good");
    printf("second strcat returned %p => %s\n", (void *)second, second);
    printf("and now first = %p => %s\n", (void *)first, first);
    printf("and now str3 = %p => %s\n", (void *)str3, str3);

    printf("Is it any surprise that strcmp(first,second) = %d?\n",
        strcmp(first,second));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So, at last we just compare str3, str3 ? I mean finally, after all modifications made to str3, str3 points to same location in memory. I just mean to ask that final call is strcmp(str3, str3), not strcmp("DayGood", "DayGoodgood"); ?

Comment: `str3` is not a pointer so it doesn't point anywhere. It's an array. And like any object in C, the address of an array is a constant for its lifetime.

Answer (score 3):

Whichever order the compiler chooses to compute the arguments to `strcmp`, `strcat` always returns its first argument.

Therefore in essence here's what happens:

```
... // execute strcat(str3, strcpy(str2, str1)) and strcat(str3, "good")
l = strcmp(str3, str3);
```

Answer (score 2):

It returns 0 because both parameters:

```
strcat(str3, strcpy(str2, str1))
```

and

```
strcat(str3, "good")
```

actually return the same thing: the memory address assigned to str3. So, strcmp returns 0 because it's comparing the variable str3 with itself.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that `strcat` is always returning the first argument passed to it make always your expression true. here is the explanation :

```
strcmp(strcat(str3, strcpy(str2, str1)), strcat(str3, "good"));
//            ^^^^                              ^^^^

// become

strcmp( str3, str3 );
```

So `strcmp` return `0` by comparing the variable to itself.

*You should know that this kind of expression is not very good because it makes the code less understandable and it can lead to undefined behavior faster than you could imagine ...*

Answer (score 1):

strcmp gets two pointers to strings as its arguments:

```
 l = strcmp(strcat(str3, strcpy(str2, str1)), strcat(str3, "good"));
```

1st step:

```
l = strcmp(str3, strcat(str3, "good"));
```

Here str3 points to the string DayGoodgoodGood.

2nd step:

```
 l = strcmp(str3,str3 );
```

Now str3 points to the string DayGoodgoodGoodgood.

This will return 0 no matter what str3 points to. Since addresses are same strcmp shouldn't even compare for optimization; just returns 0.

Answer (score 0):

`strcat`returns its first arg, that's why!

Comment: No, `strcat` returns its first argument, not a pointer to it. The first argument to `strcat` is a pointer and `strcat` returns that.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I meant that.